# How to set auto increment into non primary key?

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations, laravel-schema-builder

How would I set a database auto increment field that is not a primary key on the creation method?

The only way is using a raw query?

`DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table CHANGE field field INT(10)AUTO_INCREMENT');`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not implemented to do so. However, I found this over at the [Laravel Forums](https://laravel.io/forum/05-09-2014-how-to-create-migration-to-create-auto-increment-non-primary-column):

```
Schema::table('table', function(Blueprint $t) {
    // Add the Auto-Increment column
    $t->increments("some_column");

    // Remove the primary key
    $t->dropPrimary("table_some_column_primary");

    // Set the actual primary key
    $t->primary(array("id"));
});
```

This is not tested but should work. I am not sure about how Laravel calls their primary keys, maybe you have to check that first and adapt the `dropPrimary()` line in order to make it work.

Comment: Hi. I was able to drop the primary key without passing the `index_name`. `$t->dropPrimary()`. Laravel auto-detects the name of the primary key index for the specific column. I am using Laravel 5.5 with PostgreSQL

Comment: This does not work with MySQL: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

Comment: I was able to get this to work, but it needs to be in 3 different sections:

<pre>
Schema::create('table', function(Blueprint $t) {
    // Add the Auto-Increment column
    $t->increments("some_column");
    // Plus all other fields except actual PK
});
Schema::table('table', function(Blueprint $t) {
    // Remove the primary key
    $t->dropPrimary("table_some_column_primary");
});
Schema::table('table', function(Blueprint $t) {
    // Set the actual primary key
    $t->primary(array("id"));
});
</pre>

Comment: This worked for me (it's imporant to set an index for the autoincrement column)

`$table->uuid("id");`
`$table->increments("aux_id");`

// other colums definitions
`...`
//auto increment needs to be an index (not necessarily primary)
`$table->index(array("aux_id"));`

//after setting "normal" index, drop primary
`$table->dropPrimary();`

//add primary to the field you want
`$table->primary("id");`

Comment: Thanks @DanD - I was able to combine the last two sections into one. Maybe something is different now with Laravel 10. I had trouble using the same index name pattern but was able to use the technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45883428/1575353) - e.g. `$indexesFound = Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableIndexes('table');` and then `$table->dropPrimary($indexesFound['primary']->getName());` Obviously one could guard against the scenario where `$indexesFound['primary']` is not set and handle that accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

I do not feel safe doing some workaround at migrations, so I did this inside model file:

```
/**
 *  Setup model event hooks
 */
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    self::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->field_here = $model->max('field_here') + 1;
    });
}
```

If you want disable autoincrementing add this at the beginning of the model file:

```
public $incrementing = FALSE;
```

Comment: This can lead to bad things when dealing with concurrent scenarios.

Comment: just don't delete records? 
How about $model->dataset = Model::max('dataset') + 1;

Comment: @Luiz auto-increment, is probably bad for any concurrent scenario.

Comment: @insign Thanks, but that's not the subject

Comment: if you delete a row, you'll get duplicated values

Comment: @WoLfulus better now?

Answer (score 2):

```
Schema::table('table_name', function(Blueprint $table) {
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT AFTER after_column_name,  ADD INDEX (column_name)'); 
});
```

Comment: Please comment how this code solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The current answer does not work, auto-incrementing columns must be primary keys. I recommend using `firstOrCreate` when inserting to get the same level of uniqueness (provided you still want an auto-incrementing key available).

Answer (score 0):

i was using `pgsql`, i achieved using modifier `generatedAs()` with `laravel 9`

```
Schema::create('form_section', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id()->from(100);
    $table->unsignedInteger('form_id');
    $table->foreign('form_id')->references('id')->on('forms');
    $table->unsignedInteger('section_id');
    $table->foreign('section_id')->references('id')->on('sections');
    $table->unsignedInteger('section_sequence')->generatedAs(); //solution
    $table->timestamps($precision = 0);
});
```

Comment: is it possible to use `gerneratedAs()` with a starting value? for example starting att 1000 and up from there?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like yours, i could resolve It so Try This Example  It Works:

```
Schema::create('etendu', function (Blueprint $table) {



            $table->Increments('id_etendu');

            $table->Integer('TypeActivite');

            $table->Integer('id_activite')->unsigned();

            $table->Integer('id_wilaya')->unsigned();

            $table->Integer('id_user')->unsigned();

            // autoIncrements needs index 
            $table->index(['id_etendu']);

            // Remove the primary key
            $table->dropPrimary("id_etendu");

            $table->foreign('id_activite')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('activite')
            ->onCascade('delete');

            $table->foreign('id_wilaya')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('wilayas')
            ->onCascade('delete');

            $table->foreign('id_user')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('user')
            ->onCascade('delete');
             // make them unique
            $table->unique(['id_etendu','id_activite','id_wilaya']);
            // make it primary key
            $table->primary('id_etendu');
        });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: how would you approach my issue on this topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74269132/non-primary-auto-incrementing-integer-in-laravel-migration

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to have either both id column of type **UUID** as **primary** column and also row_number of type integer and **auto-increment**.

**laravel 10** solution:

```
Schema::create('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id');
    $table->bigIncrements('row_number')->index();

    // other columns ...

    $table->dropPrimary('row_number');
    $table->primary('id');
});
```

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key