# How can indexes be checked if they exist in a Laravel migration?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-migration

Trying to check if a unique index exists on a table when preparing a migration, how can it be achieved?

```
Schema::table('persons', function (Blueprint $table) {
    if ($table->hasIndex('persons_body_unique')) {
        $table->dropUnique('persons_body_unique');
    }
})
```

Something that looks like the above. (apparently, hasIndex() doesn't exist)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Using "doctrine-dbal" that Laravel uses is better solution:

```
Schema::table('persons', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $sm = Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager();
    $indexesFound = $sm->listTableIndexes('persons');

    if(array_key_exists("persons_body_unique", $indexesFound))
        $table->dropUnique("persons_body_unique");
});
```

Comment: As mentioned above, this should be the right answer as it goes over Laravel's Doctrine and does not use a native query.

Comment: I can confirm this works on 5.2, after i installed the doctrine-dbal package from the repo.

Comment: Be aware that `listTableIndexes()` will return the name of indexes in **lower case**.

Comment: Minor add to make copy/paste for other migrations in your future you can use the $table object to get the name.

`$indexesFound = $sm->listTableIndexes($table->getTable());`

Comment: getDoctrineSchemaManager was removed in Laravel 11

Comment: In laravel 11 you can use `in_array('persons_body_unique', Schema::getIndexListing($table->getTable())`  instead

Answer (score 16):

The mysql query

`SHOW INDEXES FROM persons`

will give you back all of the indexes on the table, however it includes additional info other than just the names. In my setup, the column containing the name is called `Key_name` so lets get a collection of key names

```
collect(DB::select("SHOW INDEXES FROM persons"))->pluck('Key_name')
```

And since it's a collection you can use `contains` so finally we have:

```
if (collect(DB::select("SHOW INDEXES FROM persons"))->pluck('Key_name')->contains('persons_body_unique')) {
    $table->dropUnique('persons_body_unique');
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer as it is not cross-dbms ("portable", not vendor-specific). The answer by @admirko is much more better as it goes over Laravel's underlaying Doctrine layer and not over a "native query".

Answer (score 5):

In the simple form, you can do this

```
Schema::table('persons', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $index_exists = collect(DB::select("SHOW INDEXES FROM persons"))->pluck('Key_name')->contains('persons_body_unique');
    if ($index_exists) {
        $table->dropUnique("persons_body_unique");
    }
})
```