# add column auto increments without primary key in Laravel migrations

Tags: laravel, migration

How to add column auto increments but not primary key in Laravel migrations and exists table, its have primary key is `id`. I'm using Laravel 5.7 and pgsql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set auto increment into non primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929776/how-to-set-auto-increment-into-non-primary-key)

Comment: I try this but it fails: `multiple primary keys for table "table_names" are not allowed`

Answer (score 0):

I guess adding an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column automatically creates a primary key for that column.

Because you are making some other column `AUTO_INCREMENT`,means you have two column with `AUTO_INCREMENT`,so Laravel is confused as it is getting two  `Primary Key`.