# Non-Primary, Auto Incrementing Integer in Laravel Migration

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I've scoured the web for this one.

What I'm trying to do:

I have a table that has a primary `id`. I need to add a column called ex. `order_number` that automatically increments starting at 1000 and up from there.

---

The Issue:

PHP doesn't seem to like this, it throws an error

```
 SQLSTATE[42P16]: Invalid table definition: 7 ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "orders" are not allowed (SQL: alter table "orders" add column "order_number" serial primary key not null)
```

---

My Code:

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $last_id = Order::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->id;
            $table->integer('order_number', true, true)->from($last_id + 10001);
        });

        foreach (Order::get() as $order) {
            $order->update([
                'order_number' => 10000 + $order->id
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Just by using `true` on the autoincrement property, looks like it tries to set the column as primary (you can have an autoincremening column that is not primary), so I think it is a "bug". I was not able to solve, but I was able to ignore that column in my project. I would recommend you to use a RAW sql expression to create it by hand, I honestly did not find another solution. You can also report this on the [official Laravel repo](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues) so someone tries to reproduce this and fix it

Comment: What is the point of having two different sequence generators iterating at the same time? They are functionally identical, just add 1000 to the ID and call it an order number.

Comment: @Sammitch I agree, that's what I ended up settling with :)

Answer (score 1):

I think we can make a work around to make it work.

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
               $table->bigIncrements('order_number');

              // if it is making both as primary key
              //drop the primary key constraint from one
              $table->dropPrimary('orders_order_number_primary');

              $table->id();
        });
    }
```

I have not tested it, but I feel it will work, even I feel, if we are using id() for primary key, may be bigIncrements will not get treated as primary key.

Using model observer, on the `created()`, you can use the id to set `order_number` or if you want to do it in `creating` also, you can do it based on last id inserted, that will be perhaps the proper way.

*Note: You have some customization on possible value for order_number, but I think you can make that workaround in model, but also I am assuming the question is about can we have two auto increment fields in a table.*

Comment: bigIncrements does get treated as a primary key, from the looks of it, anything that auto increments is considered as pk

Comment: @TimBogdanov then we need to drop primary key constraint after adding the column to keep it as only auto increment.

Comment: the issue was that it doesn't let you create an incrementing integer, to begin with.

Comment: @TimBogdanov how it will behave if we will put the id() after dropping primary constraint for order number? That should work, I guess, as we 1. added auto increment 2. drop primary constraint from auto increment and 3. add primary key. I have updated the snippet, I will try it tomorrow though, if you have time, please try once.

Answer (score 1):

No Need to use other parameters in

```
$table->integer('column name')
```

Use only :-

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $last_id = Order::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->id;
            $table->integer('order_number')->from($last_id + 10001);
        });
    }
```

Comment: right, but this doesn't auto-increment, defeating the purpose. As noted in my comments, using the id and adding 1000 to it seams to be the only solution. Which makes sense i guess.